# Emmet Sass в VSCode

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code, sass, emmet

При использовании Emmet в коде Sass (в VSCode) ставит точку запятую в конце как будто это Css код. Синтаксис стоит Sass. Такое стало происходить после последнего патча, кто то знает в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"emmet.preferences": {
    "sass.propertyEnd": "",
    "stylus.valueSeparator": " ",
    "stylus.propertyEnd": ""
}
```

Comment: Была такая же проблема, вставил этот код в настройки emmet, стало нормально

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]